# Who named the QM7 and QM9 datasets?

Tags: machine-learning

On the surface, this looks like a silly question, but I honestly can't find an answer for it.

Here's what I've found:

- The dataset was introduced in Ramakrishnan R., Dral P. *et al.*, “Quantum chemistry structures and properties of 134 kilo molecules”. Scientific Data 1 (2014). doi: [10.1038/sdata.2014.22](https://www.nature.com/articles/sdata201422). This paper doesn't contain the word *QM9*, and the dataset isn't given a name.
- The aforementioned paper gives [this link](https://springernature.figshare.com/collections/Quantum_chemistry_structures_and_properties_of_134_kilo_molecules/978904) to download the dataset. Again, *QM9* is nowhere to be found. No other name is given.
- There's a readme file in the dataset folder, copied [here](https://pastebin.com/77PE7hD0). The first line does say `Data set dsgdb9nsd`, so that's my closest lead to the dataset name.
- One of the authors of the paper (Pavlo Dral) has [a post](http://dr-dral.com/data-set-with-134-kilo-molecules/) regarding this dataset. He says,

> The data set is also called QM13 in the “Quantum Machine” website and augments previously used and smaller QM7 and QM7b data sets.

so he seemingly let someone else name it, but even then he got the number wrong (QM13 v. QM9).

On the other hand, people other than the dataset's authors name it QM9:

- The [quantum-machine.org](http://quantum-machine.org/datasets/#qm9) page
- [This paper](https://jcheminf.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s13321-019-0391-2) (none of the authors participated in Ramakrishnan's paper)
- [This master's thesis](https://aaltodoc.aalto.fi/bitstream/handle/123456789/28571/master_Ghosh_Kunal_2017.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y) (sec 2.3.1)
- [This other paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41597-019-0121-7) (again, authors are unrelated)

It's not that I dislike the name QM9. I just want to know if there's a "proper name" for the dataset and also who chose the name QM9.

Comment: Is this a chemistry question? Does the origin of the name actually matter?

Comment: @JonCuster I don't know where else to ask it, and I've seen some QM9 questions here. The name and its origin matter to me since I'd like to refer to this dataset with a name.

Comment: I think it's fair game. IIRC it's because it's a dataset from quantum mechanics (QM) and has molecules with up to 9 "heavy atoms." The various QM7 sets have up to 7 heavy atoms, QM8 set has 8, etc.

Comment: @GeoffHutchison So, seemingly, the authors left the dataset unnamed and someone else decided to use the same scheme as the GDB-n databases?

Comment: AFAIK, that's correct - and since it came from GDB, the name makes sense (e.g. the filenames). Naming a dataset isn't usually the first thought of authors.

Comment: @GeoffHutchison Fair explanation given the circumstances, even though this feels like having a child and letting his school friends name him. Huh.

Comment: @Imp54 - well, usually school children do often name each other, the origin of many nicknames for better or worse...